# (man) of (place) vs. (man) from (place)

Tags: meaning

I know 'the Oracle **of** Omaha' is a nickname for Warren Buffett.

I wondered how different its meaning would be if I wrote 'the Oracle **from** Omaha' instead.

For another example: "The eight-hour operation took place in Baltimore on Friday, and the patient, David Bennett Sr. **of** Maryland, was doing well on Monday, according to surgeons at the University of Maryland Medical Center."

If I write 'David Bennett Sr. **from** Maryland' instead, would its meaning  get different?

Comment: "Of" makes more sense when referring to a person's location; "from" makes more sense for a person's place of origin. Warren Buffett still lives in Omaha (I believe), so that's why "of" works well. Jean-Claude Van Damme, on the other hand, moved to the United States, which is why he's known as the Muscles "from" Brussels. But "from" can actually work both ways. "Of" is idiomatically used after a proper name in a newspaper - i.e. the guy from Maryland in your example; if you dropped in "from," it just wouldn't be idiomatic.

Comment: ... Whereas in sportscasting you might well expect "from" :)